# Create Live Report from the contents in a LiveDoc Document in Polarion

Tags: polarion

Is it possible to create a report (using Live Report Page) from the contents mentioned in a LiveDoc document?

E.g. I have some test cases listed in a LiveDoc document and want my report : To pick only those test cases and using a script/s generate a report for those test cases only.

If it is possible, then how ?

Answer (score 0):

It is *very* easy in a velocity wiki page:

```
  #set($q='"')
  <ul>
    #foreach($wi in $trackerService.queryWorkItems("project.id:_POL_PRJ  AND type:testcase AND document.id:${q}_SPACE_/DOC_ID$q","outlineNumber"))
      <li> $wi.id $wi.title </li>
    #end 
  </ul>
```

You can use these scripts also in Live report pages. There are some pitfalls:

- Via Lucene queries you can not retrieve referenced WI out of documents
- in Live pages you cannot use the wiki formatting but need to use HTML